# Flatbed Document Scanner

Tags: windows, editing, scanner, documents, popups

I have a flatbed scanner hooked up to my older WinXP machine. When I hit the scan button it brings up the prompt asking to what program I want to run. Is there a registry edit, program that will allow me to edit what programs are shown on this pop up list?

Comment: More information is needed in order to answer this question.  What's the model name of the scanner?  Where does the prompt originate?  Is it a built in Windows prompt, or is it an application that shipped with your scanner?  These are all necessary details.

Comment: Epson v30. Its a default Windows event prompt. Hit scan and Windows asks what program you would like to use.